# How do I create an EXE file from C# using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Windows Forms project in C#.

I want to be able to turn this into an EXE file to be able to give this out to some of my friends. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Before you say that there is an application file in the bin/debug folder, yes, I know that. The thing is that I want to be able to create this into just one file where they won't be able to access the code.

Comment: You can create a Single executable by following the instructions here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs

Comment: Bear in mind that even if you give it in just one .exe file it would be easily decompilable and your friends would be able to get a version pretty similar to your code - although syntactically may not be the same they will behave the same - by just using one of the available decompilers around

Answer (score 6):

If you want a 100% portable application :

1. Install the Nuget Package **Costura.Fody**.
   It will add all the dependencies directly into the .exe so that there are no separate .dlls or other files apart from it.

   [image: costura]
2. Change the output to **Release** and generate your project (run it or CTRL + B)

   [image: release]
3. Go to your `project folder / bin / release` and there is the `.exe`
4. Profit.